# Error Trying to Connect R to MySQL using RODBC

Tags: mysql, r, odbc, rodbc

I am attempting to connect R to a MySQL database via RODBC (in Win 7 environment), but cannot get past the following error:

```
[RODBC] ERROR: state IM014, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified     DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
```

After entering the following command:

```
odbcConnect(dsn,uid="My_UID",pwd="My_PWD")
```

I have successfully created a driver for the database by following the odbc wizard, and have installed the RODBC package into RStudio (ver 0.98.490). The MySQL is running on 32bit, I have the 32bit driver installed and working, and my RStudio is also 32bit. I know that the driver is working since both the test connection in config. works, as do queries run on excel using the driver.

What can I do to get the connection to work in R?

(Previous responses to this question seem to have been removed.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar RODBC connectivity issue using DSN, where R was crashing abruptly without any logs/error trace. I tried with DSN-less ODBC connection API, it works fine.

odbcDriverConnect("SERVERNAME=;DRIVER={};DATABASE=;UID=;PWD=;")

Steps:
1. Install ODBC driver
2. Define VNode (host, listen address, protocol)
3. Use the odbcDriverConnect API

Docs:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/vignettes/RODBC.pdf

Hope this helps.